# How to use GetxController inside my view without removing the const keyword on the constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

using `Getx`, when I have a `GetxController` and I want to use it inside my view UI, it required removing `const` on the widget constructor :

Controller :

```
class TestController extends GetxController {
// ...
}
```

View :

```
 class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWidget({super.key}); //  throws error
   final controller = Get.put(TestController());
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

it throws an error on the const line :

```
> Can't define the 'const' constructor because the field 'controller' is initialized with a non-constant value.
```

so it requires me to delete the `const`, but since adding `const` is recommended for better performance, I want to let it there and use my controller.

I could shut down this error by declaring the controller inside the `build()` method, but I guess it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaring controllers inside the `build()` method will cause to extra unnecessary `Get.put()` that will be called every time widget rebuilds.

Instead of calling your controller as a variable like this:

```
final controller = Get.put(TestController());
```

You prevent this error and let your widget `const`, by using a `getter` to get the `GetxController` like this:

```
TestController get controller => Get.put(TestController());
```

You can use the controller now simply like you will do if you declare it as `final`, and your widget is still `const`.

Consider also using `GetView<T>` since it makes you achieve the same thing:

```
class TextWidget extends GetView<TestController> {
  const TextWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("${controller.index}"); // use controller directly to access controller.
  }
}
```

You need just to specify the generic type of your controller with `GetView<T>`, then you can refer to that controller with the `controller` getter without defining it manually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a controller

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {}
```

Then create an instance of that controller inside the binding

```
class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<HomeController>(HomeController());
  }
}
```

Then extends your view with GetView and Assign HomeController to generic type of GetView

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Homepage')),
    );
  }
}
```

while navigating to that page you can initialize that binding too which will create the instance of that controller

```
await Get.to(
  () => const HomePage(),
  binding: HomeBinding(),
);
```

you can access variables and functions residing inside HomeController by using controller. and controller. i.e. controller.connectButtonAction(), controller.userName